# Isomorphism and modulo math

Tags: abstract-algebra, self-learning

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism
My  question about module 6 example 
How is general equation derived 
(a,b)->(3a+4b) mod 6 
I looked at a whole bunch things 
I am new at this thing
According to the example it mentions mod 2 and 
mod 3 for (a,b) pardon my stupidity 
shouldn’t it be. 
(a,b)->(2a+3b) mod 6

Ultimately I would like to derive my own
Help

Comment: no, with your proposal $(0,0)$ and $(0,2)$ would both map to $(0,0)$

Comment: $(a,b)\mapsto(3a+2b)\bmod6$ could also work

Comment: Oh I see if have to make sure the mapping of coordinates is 1-1

Comment: That’s correct; a mapping can’t be an isomorphism if it’s not a bijection

Comment: What happens if the general equation maps a pair not on the list. Does imply the equation is wrong

Comment: As I indicated, to have a group isomorphism, you need a mapping from one group to another that is one-to-one and onto and respects the group operations

Comment: The example is an instance of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

Answer (score 1):

A group isomorphism is a bijective (one-to-one and onto) map from one group to another that respects the group operations.  $(a,b)\mapsto(2a+3b) \bmod 6$ is not a bijection, because $(0,0)\mapsto0$ and $(0,2)\mapsto0$, so it can't be an isomorphism.